# Google App Engine import error, for django.urls

Tags: django, python-2.7, google-app-engine, django-views

I'm trying to learn Django, so I completed their multi-part tutorial (Python 2.7) and ran it locally. I got it working fine on my PC.

I need the following import, in a views.py file:

from django.urls import reverse

When I upload it to GAE, it gives me the following error:
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value: No module named urls

Is this module unavailable for the GAE, or am I doing something wrong?
(By the way, I need this import so I can use the "reverse" method, after a user submission is received in the polls app, like: HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(question.id,)))    )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reverse()` was moved from `django.core.urlresolvers` to `django.urls` in Django 1.10. The error suggests that you are using an older version of Django.

You need to import `reverse()` from the old location:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
```